# How to run this docker compose file

Tags: docker-compose

I have an error in my docker-compose file, but can't understand what is wrong.
I took it from Kubernetes tutorial.
The error is

```
yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 1, column 1
expected <block end>, but found '<block mapping start>'
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 2, column 3
```

And the file is :

```
version: "2"
  services:
    redis-master:
      image: k8s.gcr.io/redis:e2e
        ports:
          - "6379"

      redis-slave:
        image: gcr.io/google_samples/gb-redisslave:v1
        ports:
          - "6379"
        environment:
          - GET_HOSTS_FROM=dns

      frontend:
        image: gcr.io/google-samples/gb-frontend:v4
        ports:
          - "80:80"
        environment:
          - GET_HOSTS_FROM=dns
        labels:
          kompose.service.type: LoadBalancer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only issue that I can spot is that the compose file is that it's not properly indented.

Try this version of your compose file:

```
version: "2"

services:
  redis-master:
    image: k8s.gcr.io/redis:e2e
    ports:
      - "6379"
  redis-slave:
    image: gcr.io/google_samples/gb-redisslave:v1
    ports:
      - "6379"
    environment:
      - GET_HOSTS_FROM=dns
  frontend:
    image: gcr.io/google-samples/gb-frontend:v4
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    environment:
      - GET_HOSTS_FROM=dns
    labels:
      kompose.service.type: LoadBalancer
```

For more details on YAML structure, [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/yaml/yaml_basics.htm) is a good starting point.

Comment: oh, I see that there should not be spaces before `services`